# Disable other languages in login screen

Tags: kubuntu, login-screen, input-language

I have two languages on my computer, but my password is in English. Is there any way to allow only English input when being required to login?

A similar question has been asked before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348050/login-screen-password-language), but there was no answer to this question.

I am using Kubuntu 16.04