# atomaically change keyboard language to login password

Tags: login-screen, lock-screen

How can I change the settings in Ubuntu so that I'll be able to unlock the system using keyboard's primary layout and not the one which I was working with when I locked the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login screen password language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348050/login-screen-password-language)