# Cannot change language after wake up

Tags: boot, keyboard, suspend

I have the following simple problem. When my laptop goes to sleep (Ubuntu 18.04 lts), and I forgot to change the keyboard to English, I cannot change it back to log back in. Using the shortcut appears to change it, but it in fact does not change it. In the end I have to do a hard reboot and after logging back in, it indeed has kept the non-English keyboard it went to sleep with.
Any suggestion to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install the Power Management tool:  `sudo apt install pm-tools`. Read the docs shown by `dpkg -L pm-tools`. You can do you keyboard change as your system goes into or out of hibernation or suspension.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, scripts on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348050/login-screen-password-language) Q&A works on 18.04LTS not on 20.04LTS